# Custom Scrollbar in GWT

Tags: html, css, gwt

I would like to put in my own graphics instead of the OS dependent boring scrollbars for the website I'm building. Is there a way to do this in GWT?

Comment: "I want to make that text **blinking** and moving from side to side instead of boring static text" was the downfall of many aspiring web devs in the Geocities era ;) Please don't make their mistake. Default look equals familiar ground, if you put some sleek looking scrollbars, the average user might find them less intuitive than the standard, boring looking ones. And if the look really matters to them, they'll just install a skin for their browser :)

Comment: Igor is wrong, many OS native scrollbars sucks, and are too intrusive, so if you need, let's say scrollbar for that small, overflow:auto, box, why not make a better one? Inspire yourself: http://wave.google.com

Comment: Some OS native scrollbars look ugly, but they have the advantage of being literally as fast as possible, and users already know how to use the native scrollbars. Unless your scrollbar does *exactly* what the native scrollbar does *and* is just as fast, then your users will face some confusion/annoyance. *And* it means you have to continue to support and debug issues with your scrollbar, forever. It's just not worth it, IMO.

Comment: @jason, igor, slaks: I guess you are right. Using the native elements is always the best 
thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution i found is to create my own scroll panel. The scroll bar is wrapped around a Focus panel. I've added Mousedown, mousemove and mouseout handlers to the focus panel. Recording the mouse movements and moving the contents accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Slaks.  Best bet is to use the Jquery plugin JScrollpane.

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Comment: Is it possible to incorporate jquery in gwt?

Answer (score 0):

I have posted my answer in fallowing link [GWT CustomScrollPanel example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020102/gwt-customscrollpanel-example). But this won't work for IE just like gmail.