# How to create custom scrollBar in CustomScrollPanel (GWT 2.4)?

Tags: gwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom Scrollbar in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686099/custom-scrollbar-in-gwt)

I want to use CustomScrollPanel of GWT 2.4
How can I create my own scrollPanel and replace it with NativeVerticalScrollbar that in CustomScrollPanel default? What layout of scrollbar should be?
Thanks