# GWT CustomScrollPanel example

Tags: gwt, scrollbar

I found out about GWT's CustomScrollPanel and how you can customize the scroll bar, but I can't find any examples or how to set it up.  Are there any examples out there that show custom scrollbars in use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you would customize the native scrollbars, however you could also develop your own scrollbar classes that implement VerticalScrollbar and HorizontalScrollbar that are a lot more customizable.

Resource (style) definitions:

```
public class ScrollResourcesContainer {

    public interface ScrollPanelResources extends CustomScrollPanel.Resources
    {
        @Override
        @Source( { "ScrollPanel.css", CustomScrollPanel.Style.DEFAULT_CSS } )
        CustomScrollPanel.Style customScrollPanelStyle();
    }

    public interface HorizontalResources extends NativeHorizontalScrollbar.Resources
    {
        @Override
        @Source( { "HorizontalScrollbar.css", NativeHorizontalScrollbar.StyleTransparant.DEFAULT_CSS } )
        NativeHorizontalScrollbar.Style nativeHorizontalScrollbarStyle();
    }

    public interface VerticalResources extends NativeVerticalScrollbar.Resources
    {
        @Override
        @Source( { "VerticalScrollbar.css", NativeVerticalScrollbar.StyleTransparant.DEFAULT_CSS } )
        NativeVerticalScrollbar.Style nativeVerticalScrollbarStyle();
    }
}
```

Usage through `CustomScrollPanel` :

```
    CustomScrollPanel csp = new CustomScrollPanel((ScrollResourcesContainer.ScrollPanelResources) GWT.create(ScrollResourcesContainer.ScrollPanelResources.class));
    csp.setHorizontalScrollbar(new NativeHorizontalScrollbar((HorizontalResources) GWT.create(HorizontalResources.class)),
    AbstractNativeScrollbar.getNativeScrollbarHeight());
    csp.setVerticalScrollbar(new NativeVerticalScrollbar((VerticalResources) GWT.create(VerticalResources.class)),
    AbstractNativeScrollbar.getNativeScrollbarWidth());
```

Comment: Are the css files the ones that allow customization? could you provide a sample for VerticalScrollbar.css?

Comment: Yes they are, but there isn't a whole lot you can do because they are using the native scroll bars, if you want a lot of customization you might want to create a fully custom DOM implementation. For examples you should check out the GWT source by unzipping gwt-user.jar and looking in com\google\gwt\user\client\ui at AbstractNativeScrollbar.java and NativeVerticalScrollbar.java NativeVerticalScrollbar.ui.xml and NativeVerticalScrollbarTransparent.css.

Answer (score 2):

To get the sleek scrollbars for vertical scrollbar in gwt, you need to add following code in the **VerticalScrollbar.css**. 
Which won't work for IE just like gmail.

```
/* Turn on a 16x16 scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

/* Turn on single button up on top, and down on bottom */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment {
    display: block;
}

/* Turn off the down area up on top, and up area on bottom */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:increment,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:decrement {
    display: none;
}

/* Place The scroll down button at the bottom */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment {
    background-image: url(images/scroll_cntrl_dwn.png);
}

/* Place The scroll up button at the up */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement {
    background-image: url(images/scroll_cntrl_up.png);
}

/* Top area above thumb and below up button */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:start {
    background-image: url(images/scroll_gutter_top.png), url(images/scroll_gutter_mid.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
}

/* Bottom area below thumb and down button */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:end {
    background-image: url(images/scroll_gutter_btm.png), url(images/scroll_gutter_mid.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
    background-position: bottom left, 0 0;
}

/* The thumb itself */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    height: 56px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(images/scroll_thumb.png) 8 0 8 0 stretch stretch;
    border-width: 8 0 8 0;
}
```

Comment: similarly you can do for horizontal scrollbar also.  Please check the following link for more details. http://almaer.com/blog/creating-custom-scrollbars-with-css-how-css-isnt-great-for-every-task

Comment: Thanks for the VerticalScrollbar.css, this really helped a lot. Do you have a sample HorizontalScrollbar.css?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in having the CSS for both vertical/horizontal, this is what I'm using.

**HorizontalScrollbar.css**

```
/* ***********
 * SCROLLBAR *
 * ***********/
.nativeHorizontalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

/* *************
 * BUTTON AREA *
 * *************/
.nativeHorizontalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal
{
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* Increment scroll left/right button. */
.nativeHorizontalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
.nativeHorizontalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment
{
    display: block;

    width: 10px;
    height: 8px;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 10px 8px;
}

/* Increment scroll left button. */
.nativeHorizontalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement
{
    background-image: url('images/scroll-left.png');
}

/* Increment scroll right button. */
.nativeHorizontalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment
{
    background-image: url('images/scroll-right.png');
}

/* Jump left/right buttons. */
.nativeHorizontalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start:increment,
.nativeHorizontalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:decrement
{
    display: none;
}

/* ******************
 * TRACKING SECTION *
 * ******************/
.nativeHorizontalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal
{
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* Area between the thumb and the left button. */
.nativeHorizontalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:horizontal:start
{

}

/* Area between the thumb and and right button. */
.nativeHorizontalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:horizontal:end
{

}

/* 
 * The tracking area.
 * This is the area that the thumb travels along.
 */
.nativeHorizontalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece
{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

/* The tracking piece. */
.nativeHorizontalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal
{
    height: 15px;

    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);

    border: none;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

/* ********
 * CORNER *
 * ********/
.nativeHorizontalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-corner:horizontal
{
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* *********
 * RESIZER *
 * *********/
.nativeHorizontalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-resizer:horizontal
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

**VerticalScrollbar.css**
/* ***********
 * SCROLLBAR *
 * ***********/

```
.nativeVerticalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

/* *************
 * BUTTON AREA *
 * *************/
.nativeVerticalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical
{
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* Increment scroll up/down buttons. */
.nativeVerticalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
.nativeVerticalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment
{
    display: block;

    width: 10px;
    height: 8px;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 10px 8px;
}

/* Increment scroll up button. */
.nativeVerticalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement
{
    background-image: url('images/scroll-up.png');
}

/* Increment scroll down button. */
.nativeVerticalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment
{
    background-image: url('images/scroll-down.png');
}

/* Jump up/down buttons. */
.nativeVerticalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:increment,
.nativeVerticalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:decrement
{
    display: none;
}

/* ******************
 * TRACKING SECTION *
 * ******************/
.nativeVerticalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical
{
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* Area between the thumb and the up button. */
.nativeVerticalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:start
{

}

/* Area between the thumb and and down button. */
.nativeVerticalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:end
{

}

/* 
 * The tracking area.
 * This is the area that the thumb travels along.
 */
.nativeVerticalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece
{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

/* The tracking piece. */
.nativeVerticalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical
{
    height: 15px;

    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);

    border: none;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

/* ********
 * CORNER *
 * ********/
.nativeVerticalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-corner:vertical
{
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* *********
 * RESIZER *
 * *********/
.nativeVerticalScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-resizer:vertical
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```