# GWT - ScrollPane look and feel

Tags: java, gwt

I am just wondering is there a optimal way to modify ScrollPane look&feel with CSS? I mean how to make it more narrow or gray color or change arrow buttons etc?

Or there is some another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The custom scroll panel is the nearest thing to a nice scroll panel in gwt [GWT CustomScrollPanel example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020102/gwt-customscrollpanel-example)

Css styling on default scroll sucks. Facebook, gmail, wave, etc use a emulated scroll and never browser native scroll....

Comment: Could you give more details... Some emulator's snippets for GWT?

Comment: Unfortunately i have not found anything yet. Scroll styling till now has been an excercise of putting lipstick on hideous pig. We simply let it as is and design gui to avoid scrolls. Use top or bottom floating buttons if it is a must in your case.