# GWT CustomScrollPanel - how do I stop default scrollbars showing on top of my custom ones?

Tags: gwt, scroll, scrollbar, vaadin, custom-scrolling

I tried doing a `CustomScrollPanel` with my own `HorizontalScrollbar` and `VerticalScrollbar` implementations which each return a Vaadin `DrawingArea` from `asWidget()`. The `DrawingArea` appears to be rendered but only underneath native scrollbars (which are *not* part of the `DrawingArea` Widget). I was expecting them to show *instead* of the native scrollbars. How do I ensure this is the case?

(P.S. I tried the example at [GWT CustomScrollPanel example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020102/gwt-customscrollpanel-example) to no avail.)

Comment: Did you try this, in gwt.xml file remove the theme used and running project again.