# HTML5: set scrollbar area backrground color

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

I have an element with a scroll bar (overflow-y: auto).
I set the background-color of my element to a specific color (say, blue). However, the area of the scrollbar remain with a white background color.

How can i change the scrollbar area background color to the elements background color?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Comment: try this: http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar

Answer (score 1):

GWT introduced [Custom Scroll Panel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CustomScrollPanel.html) from 2.4 version. I think you can give this a try. You should make yourself familiar with [CSS Resources](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle#CssResource) if you want to change colurs, images and all. You can also refer the following links

[GWT CustomScrollPanel example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020102/gwt-customscrollpanel-example)

http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Answer (score -1):

You can't change the colors of the scrollbar. You will have to use 3rd party scroll bar replacement.