# How to apply styles for GWT scrollbar

Tags: gwt

I 've tried to give css to scrollpanel in GWT. But its not working.

The problem is I want to change the foregroung and background colors and also the width of scrollers.

Is it possible? can any1 suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it is based on the browser user agent.

For example : **For Chrome** You need to do something like,

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 3px; height: 3px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {  background-color: #666; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {  background-color: #999;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece { background-color: #ffffff;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { height: 50px; background-color: #666; border-radius: 3px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner { background-color: #999;}}
::-webkit-resizer { background-color: #666;}
```

Please refer this [Link](http://codemug.com/html/custom-scrollbars-using-css/)

Answer (score 0):

GWT scrollbars are simply html ones, so you can style them in the same way you would do with plain html: using css.

Add a class to your `ScrollPanel` and set the styles in your .css files, or set styles to it using java methods.

But you have to be aware that styling scroll-bars is not a standard thing, webkit supports it via vendor-css-properties and the same with IE, but unfortunately you will not be able to style FF.

UPDATE:

As @Andrea suggest in the comment below, if you can change in your app `ScrollPanel` by `CustomScrollPanel` you have much more options to customize bars.

In this case you have to provide your own bars because by default it uses browser native ones. This [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020102/gwt-customscrollpanel-example) can help you.

Comment: But you can use a `CustomScrollPanel` and provide your own scrollbar implementation, styled the way you want.